# Accessing Remote Website on Webserver in Office Building

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, networking, vps

I have an apache webserver which is in managed office building. I don't know much about how the network is setup and I was wondering if there is a way I could access a intranet website on the webserver from outside the the office building? The office has a static IP.

Comment: Yes, there will most likely be a way, but since we know even less about the network, we can't tell you how.

Comment: Detail. Is. Everything.

Comment: Running Linux Centos 5. Using Windows XP/7 outside. Thats all i know too :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teamviewer or similar software would allow you access into the internal network from outside.

Answer (score 1):

If you setup a VPN or a tunnel on/to the webserver, then you might be able to do this. But only if the firewall rules allow you to.